# Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, derby

I am trying to run integration test for my project and I am using `Apache Derby` for that. My main classes look like

**integration/pom.xml**

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.carlspring.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>derby-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>${derby.port}</port>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-derby</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <groups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.PreIntegration
                    </groups>
                    <excludedGroups>
                        com.learner.persistence.harness.Integration
                    </excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.cargo.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>wildfly8x</containerId>
                        <dependencies combine.children="append">
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                                <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <systemProperties combine.children="append">
                            <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
                            </hibernate.dialect>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                                cargo.datasource.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver|
                                cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:${derby.port}/integrationDB|
                                cargo.datasource.jndi=${datasource.jndi}|
                                cargo.datasource.username=${datasource.user}|
                                cargo.datasource.password=${datasource.password}
                            </cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <properties>
                                <context>earth</context>
                            </properties>
                            <pingURL>http://localhost:9090/earth/rest/hello</pingURL>
                            <pingTimeout>36000</pingTimeout>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-container</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

**DataSetupTest**

```
@Category(PreIntegration.class)
public class DataSetup {
    @Rule
    public final JpaRule jpaRule = new JpaRule(JpaRule.Derby.directory, "unit-testing-pu");

    @Test
    public void setupData() throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {
        System.out.println("Setting up IT Database");
        com.learner.database.DataSetupTest.runLiquibaseUpdate(jpaRule);
    }
}
```

**PersonsIT**

```
@Category(Integration.class)
public class PersonsIT extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Rule
    public final JpaRule jpaRule = new JpaRule(JpaRule.Derby.client, "unit-testing-pu");


    @Test
    public void testGetPersons() throws IOException {
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        final WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:9090/earth/rest/persons");
        final Response response = webTarget
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        assertStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK, response);
        final JsonNode responsePayload = parseResponse(response);
        assertEquals(5, responsePayload.size());
    }
}
```

**DerbyClient**

```
public class DerbyClient implements DataSourceDefinition {

    private final String database;

    public DerbyClient() {
        this("integrationDB");
    }

    public DerbyClient(@Nonnull final String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static String getPort() {
        return System.getProperty("derby.port", "1527");
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getPersistenceProperties() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, EmbeddedDerby.DERBY_TEN_TEN_DIALECT);
        map.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_URL, EmbeddedDerby.JDBC_URL_PROTOCOL + "//localhost:" + getPort() + "/" + database);
        map.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_DRIVER, "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        map.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_USER, System.getProperty("datasource.user", "APP"));
        map.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_PASSWORD, System.getProperty("datasource.password", "nonemptypassword"));
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public void before() {
    }

    @Override
    public void after() {
    }
}
```

When I run this module, I see

```
                -------------------------------------------------------
                 T E S T S
                -------------------------------------------------------
                SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
                SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
                SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/harith/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
                SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
                SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
                Running com.learner.integration.DataSetup
                log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.learner.persistence.harness.DerbyDirectory).
                log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
                log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
                Setting up IT Database
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Dropping Database Objects in schema: APP.APP
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/01.xml::09222014.0639::harit: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/01.xml::09222014.0639::harit: Table person created
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/01.xml::09222014.0639::harit: ChangeSet liquibase/2014/01.xml::09222014.0639::harit ran successfully in 10ms
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/01.xml::09222014.0639::harit: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: New row inserted into person
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: New row inserted into person
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: New row inserted into person
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: New row inserted into person
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: New row inserted into person
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: ChangeSet liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit ran successfully in 18ms
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: liquibase/changelog.xml: liquibase/2014/02.xml::09222014.0844::harit: Reading from APP.DATABASECHANGELOG
                INFO 9/28/14 8:36 AM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
                Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.988 sec - in com.learner.integration.DataSetup

                Results :

                Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

                [INFO] 
                [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ integration ---
                [INFO] Packaging webapp
                [INFO] Assembling webapp [integration] in [/Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/java_ee_multiple_persistence/integration/target/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
                [INFO] Processing war project
                [INFO] Webapp assembled in [64 msecs]
                [INFO] Building war: /Users/harith/code/IdeaProjects/others/java_ee_multiple_persistence/integration/target/integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
                [INFO] 
                [INFO] --- derby-maven-plugin:1.8:start (start-derby) @ integration ---
                [INFO] Initializing Derby server control for localhost/127.0.0.1
                [INFO] Starting the Derby server ...
                Sun Sep 28 08:36:34 PDT 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.1.1 - (1458268) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
                [INFO] Derby ping-pong: [OK]
                [INFO] 
            ...snipped
                [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:311)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1144)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:446)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:452)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:420)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:379)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:422)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:513)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:142)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'integrationDB' with class loader ClassRealm[plugin>org.carlspring.maven:derby-maven-plugin:1.8, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2503dbd3], see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSLAN
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:279)
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 32 more
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: ERROR XJ040: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'integrationDB' with class loader ClassRealm[plugin>org.carlspring.maven:derby-maven-plugin:1.8, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2503dbd3], see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSLAN
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.completeSqlca(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseRdbAccessFailed(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseAccessRdbError(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseACCRDBreply(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readAccessDatabase(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source) [derbyclient-10-11-1-1.jar:]
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 34 more
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:43,348 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/EarthDS
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:43,355 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:43,365 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:43,446 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:44,328 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-12) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.5-jbossorg-3 20140128-1641 for context '/earth'
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,343 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-12) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.learner.services.configuration.EarthApplication
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,500 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /earth
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "earth.war" (runtime-name : "earth.war")
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name : "cargocpc.war")
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
                [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 08:36:45,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started in 6723ms - Started 396 of 454 services (100 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)              
                -------------------------------------------------------
                 T E S T S
                -------------------------------------------------------
                Running com.learner.integration.HelloIT
                Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.513 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.learner.integration.PersonsIT
                testGetPersons(com.learner.integration.PersonsIT)  Time elapsed: 0.513 sec  <<< ERROR!
                javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
                    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
                    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
                    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
                    at com.learner.persistence.harness.JpaRule.before(JpaRule.java:104)
         ...snipped
              org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
                Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
                    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
                    at ...snipped
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
                    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
                    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
                    at com.learner.persistence.harness.JpaRule.before(JpaRule.java:104)
                    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
 ...snipped

                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:113)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:85)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:134)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
                Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'integrationDB' with class loader ClassRealm[plugin>org.carlspring.maven:derby-maven-plugin:1.8, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2503dbd3], see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSLAN
                    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
                    at ...snipped
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
                    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
                    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
                    at com.learner.persistence.harness.JpaRule.before(JpaRule.java:104)
                    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
 ...snipped
                    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:113)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:85)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:134)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
                    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: A little, late, but did you get your problem sorted out? (I'm the main developer of the `derby-maven-plugin`). What version of Derby are you using? (You might need to add a dependency of the `<plugin/>` to the newest Derby). What version of Maven are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Derby exception: "Failed to start database ... see next exception for details", this may help: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain